# Phantomjs - Ajax calls on the page doesnt get executed

Tags: javascript, ajax, cron, phantomjs

I'm using phantomjs to make a get request to a URL with parameters.

The problem is the server returns some data and i'm using javascript on that page to do some logic. Once the logic is done, i'm using ajax to post the data back to the server.

I now need this URL to be called through a cron job. When i open the URL from chrome, everything works fine. But i cant run it from a CRON.

I thought using phantomjs would help resolve this problem but even phantomjs does not execute javascript code on the remote request.

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this?

Comment: I'm not sure, I understand what you're trying to do. Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24219473/starting-phantomjs-from-a-script-in-a-cronjob)?

Comment: @ArtjomB.Yes, thats not what i'm looking for. I need to call a URL on the server(GET Request) that sends data down. I use laravel for the server stuff. It returns an HTML view with raw data. I then use js to do some complex logic on that data. At the end of the page is an ajax request to the server to post the computed data back to the server. For some reason, phantomjs does not execute the ajax call. I'm lost as to how to approach this problem. Hope this comment has helped you understand the problem better.

Comment: What does this have to do with a cron job? You can start by showing your (reduced, but runnable) code.

Comment: sure i'd love to share the code, but its got a lot of dependencies. The reason i've got to do this via a cron is because i wrote the entire logic using js. Now my requirement is to be able to have a history of all the computed data, and this data has to be sent over at the end of each day back to the server. Hence, the cron. I just need to be able to execute javascript code without using a browser from a CRON job. If i can get phantom to do this, doing the cron shouldnt be difficult.

Comment: its been only a day ive discovered phantom. Maybe i'm missing something. Can phantom execute javascript code in a page that its calling? ex. http://example.com/ajax-test. Lets say that URL had a few ajax call to other services. Can phantom execute all the ajax calls on that page?

Comment: @ArtjomB. here is a small fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/pmsx0gw4/