# PhantomJS not working only in cron job

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cron, phantomjs

I have a Python script that uses PhantomJS. When I run the script directly, it works perfectly. When I run it in a cron job, I get:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: 
Message: Unable to start phantomjs with ghostdriver: 
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'phantomjs'
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Oh, by the way, any other drivers (such as Firefox) work even in cron jobs; it's just PhantomJS that doesn't work.

Comment: Seems like cron user does not have permission to execute PhantomJS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Starting phantomJS from a script in a cronjob](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24219473/starting-phantomjs-from-a-script-in-a-cronjob)

Comment: @ArtjomB. I've tried the solutions in that answer; it didn't work.