# Phantomjs is not working in crontab - Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, cron, raspberry-pi, phantomjs

I want to run a phantomjs script from crontab on my Raspberry Pi 3 but it is not working.

I have a phantomjs script with this code:

```
console.log('Hello world');
phantom.exit();
```

if I run this manuel from the terminal, it works. But if I run this script from the crontab, I become no output.

terminal command:

```
phantomjs /home/pi/Desktop/testjs.js > /home/pi/Desktop/testjs.txt
```

In my crontab i have added this line:

```
* * * * * phantomjs /home/Desktop/testjs.js > /home/pi/Desktop/testjs.txt
```

The output is a empty file.

Then I have tested all answers from this question [Starting phantomJS from a script in a cronjob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24219473/starting-phantomjs-from-a-script-in-a-cronjob) but all have the same output, a empty file. I have tested every answer alone and combined.

Also I have created a Shell script

```
#!/bin/sh
phantomjs /home/pi/Desktop/testjs.js > /home/pi/Desktop/testjs.txt
```

but the same empty output file. If I run it from the terminal it works.

After that all I have tested every command with the phantomjs absolute path:

```
/usr/local/bin/phantomjs  /home/pi/Desktop/testjs.js > /home/pi/Desktop/testjs.txt
```

But nothing works...

I also tried to use the sudo crontab.

Here the syslog output:

> Jul 26 09:47:01 raspberrypi CRON[26612]: (pi) CMD
>   (/home/pi/Desktop/testjs.js > /home/pi/Desktop/testjs.txt)
>
> Jul 26 09:48:01 raspberrypi CRON[27156]: (pi) CMD
>   (/home/pi/Desktop/testjs.js > /home/pi/Desktop/testjs.txt)
>
> Jul 26 09:49:01 raspberrypi CRON[27629]: (pi) CMD
>   (/home/pi/Desktop/testjs.js > /home/pi/Desktop/testjs.txt)
>
> Jul 26 09:50:01 raspberrypi CRON[28015]: (pi) CMD
>   (/home/pi/Desktop/testjs.js > /home/pi/Desktop/testjs.txt)
>
> Jul 26 09:51:01 raspberrypi CRON[28434]: (pi) CMD
>   (/home/pi/Desktop/testjs.js > /home/pi/Desktop/testjs.txt)
>
> Jul 26 09:52:01 raspberrypi CRON[28859]: (pi) CMD
>   (/home/pi/Desktop/testjs.js > /home/pi/Desktop/testjs.txt)
>
> Jul 26 09:53:01 raspberrypi CRON[29209]: (pi) CMD (phantomjs
>   /home/pi/Desktop/testjs.js >> /home/pi/Desktop/testlog.txt)
>
> Jul 26 09:54:01 raspberrypi CRON[29709]: (pi) CMD (phantomjs
>   /home/pi/Desktop/testjs.js >> /home/pi/Desktop/testlog.txt)
>
> Jul 26 09:55:01 raspberrypi CRON[30215]: (pi) CMD (phantomjs
>   /home/pi/Desktop/testjs.js >> /home/pi/Desktop/testlog.txt)
>
> Jul 26 09:56:01 raspberrypi CRON[30606]: (pi) CMD (phantomjs
>   /home/pi/Desktop/testjs.js >> /home/pi/Desktop/testlog.txt)
>
> Jul 26 09:57:01 raspberrypi CRON[31070]: (pi) CMD
>   (/usr/local/bin/phantomjs /home/pi/Desktop/testjs.js >>
>   /home/pi/Desktop/testlog.txt)
>
> Jul 26 09:58:02 raspberrypi CRON[31490]: (pi) CMD
>   (/usr/local/bin/phantomjs /home/pi/Desktop/testjs.js >>
>   /home/pi/Desktop/testlog.txt)
>
> Jul 26 09:59:01 raspberrypi CRON[31901]: (pi) CMD
>   (/usr/local/bin/phantomjs /home/pi/Desktop/testjs.js >>
>   /home/pi/Desktop/testlog.txt)
>
> Jul 26 10:00:01 raspberrypi CRON[32283]: (pi) CMD
>   (/usr/local/bin/phantomjs /home/pi/Desktop/testjs.js >>
>   /home/pi/Desktop/testlog.txt)
>
> Jul 26 10:00:01 raspberrypi CRON[32284]: (root) CMD
>   (/usr/local/bin/phantomjs /home/pi/Desktop/testjs.js >>
>   /home/pi/Desktop/testlog.txt)

How can I solve this problem? I have no more ideas.

Comment: Try `* * * * * phantomjs /home/Desktop/testjs.js > /home/pi/Desktop/testjs.txt
2>&1` to redirect stderr, too. This should help to debug the problem.

Comment: check the commands output at `/var/spool/mail/{user}` if you are executing as root user will be `root`

Comment: @SachchitBansal if have no files in the mail directory :/ is this because the MTA Error in cron? I have searched for them and the peoples says I can ignor it.

Comment: @scai where should get the output of the debug? I have tried your codeline and this `* * * * * phantomjs /home/Desktop/testjs.js &> /home/pi/Desktop/testjs.txt` but I have no output in the file and nothing more in the syslog file

Comment: The `&>` redirect is bash-specific and doesn't work in crontab. Please add the redirect as specified in my comment.

Comment: @scai ok, but where I find the output?

Comment: Both stdout and stderr will be redirected to /home/pi/Desktop/testjs.txt.

Comment: the file is empty like before